# How can I restore structure after loading table with list-columns with Pandas.read_gpq?

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I have a BQ table which contains nested records. A single record looks similar to this:

```
{
    "event_date": "2018-11-14",
    "event_params": [
        {
            "string": "foo",
            "int": null
        },
        {
            "string": "52.49",
            "int": null
        }
    ]
}
```

You can represent this in pandas / a CSV by duplication. In the specific case of the single record from above, it would become two rows:

```
,event_date   event_params.string  event_params.int
1,2018-11-14  foo                  null
2,2018-11-14  52.49                null
```

Please note that the export like this is a one-way option. There is no way to tell if the two rows `1` and `2` belong to a single record or to two. One solution is to add an identifier to each record.

**Does BQ have an internal identifier for records?**

With

```
SELECT * FROM `my-table.foobar.events_20181110`
```

I don't get an row identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does BQ have an internal identifier for records?

You can generate such identifier - see examples below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT ['a', 'b', 'c'] arr UNION ALL
  SELECT ['x', 'y'] 
)
SELECT id, item FROM (
  SELECT GENERATE_UUID() id, arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), UNNEST(arr) item
```

with result

```
Row id                                      item     
1   4f47d6c2-a6d8-4923-8c20-5836a9a89d36    a    
2   4f47d6c2-a6d8-4923-8c20-5836a9a89d36    b    
3   4f47d6c2-a6d8-4923-8c20-5836a9a89d36    c    
4   1d348ac5-ec5a-4065-a4ec-46404a7ca193    x    
5   1d348ac5-ec5a-4065-a4ec-46404a7ca193    y
```

or

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT ['a', 'b', 'c'] arr UNION ALL
  SELECT ['x', 'y'] 
)
SELECT id, item FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() id, arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), UNNEST(arr) item
```

with result as

```
Row id  item     
1   1   a    
2   1   b    
3   1   c      
4   2   x    
5   2   y
```

Have in mind that second example is less scalable because of use of  ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: Thank you very much for this awesome answer!